# How to timeout a connection after certain time period, say 15s is over

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am trying to **implement a connection timeout for any connection that exceeds 15s even if the connection is active**. We are facing an issue with multipart image upload where some image randomly takes over a minute to upload, sometimes a couple of minutes. The same image takes less than a second to upload in the subsequent requests. 
We are uploading the image from an IoT device. As we have limited access to the device, we are unable to implement the timeout on the device end, and therefore have to do it at the server-side.
I am using Nginx, gunicorn and django.

**Also, I have already tried implementing these settings**:

*For nginx* :

```
#To have them timeout after just 1s

keepalive_timeout           1;
proxy_connect_timeout       1;
proxy_send_timeout          1;
proxy_read_timeout          1;
send_timeout                1;
```

*For Gunicorn* :

```
--timeout 1
```

With these settings, I expected to close any connection that went over 1s. However, the request is completing even if it takes 5 mins.

Going through the internet, I could only find answers and tutorials for increasing the timeout, with these same settings, so I thought the reverse was also true. Seems like that is not the case.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: easiest way. Try this package-  pip install django-session-idle-timeout

Comment: As I said, the request is completing. I am able to get result at the end of the request. It is just that the time taken is abnormal. Much more than other requests.